# How to get latest three files from a remote server via python?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, fabric

I created ten files with the shell script `touch.sh` on the server `test2`:

```
root@test2:/sites/buildglasses-qa.walmart.com/ftp/walmart# cat touch.sh 
for i in {1..10}
do 
    touch WMI_Order_Req_409313_$i.xml
    sleep 1
done

root@test2:/sites/buildglasses-qa.walmart.com/ftp/walmart# ls 
touch.sh                     WMI_Order_Req_409313_2.xml  WMI_Order_Req_409313_5.xml  WMI_Order_Req_409313_8.xml
WMI_Order_Req_409313_10.xml  WMI_Order_Req_409313_3.xml  WMI_Order_Req_409313_6.xml  WMI_Order_Req_409313_9.xml
WMI_Order_Req_409313_1.xml   WMI_Order_Req_409313_4.xml  WMI_Order_Req_409313_7.xml
```

Server `test` can connect to remote server `test2` via ssh without passphrase prompt.
**I want to get latest three files from remote server `test2` on test.**

**Use Farbic:**
The following is my doing with farbic.I encountered a problem.
Who can give me an solve with `farbic` Or `subprocess`,or a better ways? Thanks.

```
root@test:~# cat fabfile.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf8 -*-

from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.project import rsync_project

env.user = 'root'
env.host_string =  "test2"


def getremote():
    code_dir = '/sites/buildglasses-qa.walmart.com/ftp/walmart'
    with cd(code_dir):
        cmd = '''ls -lt WMI_Order_Req* |sed -n '1,3p' |awk '{print $9}' |tr "\n" " ";echo'''
        output = run(cmd)
        print output
        get(output,'/tmp')

getremote()
```

[image]

**Use Python:**

```
root@test:~# cat get.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf8 -*-
# Power by will yu2016-09-06 10:49:06

import subprocess
import os

cmd="ls -t /sites/buildglasses-qa.walmart.com/ftp/walmart/WMI_Order_Req_*|head -2"
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "test2", cmd], shell=False,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
print result
```

[image]
I am sad. I donnot know what is next to do.

Comment: I recommend [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) to control command line utilities from python + [scp](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) or [rsync](http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/) for copying files between servers

Comment: I updated my description.
I tried to use Python, then I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Could you give me more information?Thanks.

Comment: Error is clear, please look at the file names in first image you attached. First file has complete path but second and third don't have full path. Try to give full path to both the file. If it won't work then get single file from sever instead of getting all files at once

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.